# class io.prometheus.metrics.exporter.servlet.jakarta.PrometheusMetricsServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: servlets, jetty, prometheus, jakarta-migration

Is there anyway to convert io.prometheus.metrics.exporter.servlet.jakarta to javax?
I am not getting any depedency regarding io.prometheus.metrics.exporter.servlet for Javax.

I register a servlet mapping for Prometheus metrics in your `web.xml`

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>prometheus-metrics</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.prometheus.metrics.exporter.servlet.jakarta.PrometheusMetricsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>prometheus-metrics</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/metrics</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-instrumentation-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-exporter-servlet-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting following error:

```
Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@43ecfeb5{CZ3002_assignment2,/LoginStruts2,file:///home/user/Downloads/Struct/Struts2-Login/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///home/user/Downloads/Struct/Struts2-Login/src/main/webapp/}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class io.prometheus.metrics.exporter.servlet.jakarta.PrometheusMetricsServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
```

Not sure the last makes any sense, but I ran out of ideas.

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: Tomcat? You're using Jetty 9. This isn't Jakartified. You need a minimum of Jetty 11. See abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: [Jetty 11 and older is now at End of Community Support](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/10485).  Use Jetty 12 (you can use the `ee8` environment to maintain `javax.servlet.*` namespace, or `ee10` environment for the `jakarta.servlet.*` namespace)

Comment: I am using this plugin 
               <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.47.v20220610</version>

and for jetty-maven-plugin I don't think version 12 is available. What to do?

Comment: @Bulbul jetty-maven-plugin on Jetty 12 is available, but you have to understand which environment you want to use - see https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#get-up-and-running